# Change values in a variable in dataframe: ≥16 to "1", ＜16 to “0”?

Tags: r, dataframe

If I have a dataframe `data` with a variable `CESD`, I want to change the values ≥ 16 in `CESD` to "1", and ＜ 16 to "0" (note: there are NA in this vector and I hope to neglect them), what R function can I use?

I tried `mutate()` in dplyr package, but it doesn't work

```
library(tidyverse)
data = data %>%
  mutate(CESD = recode(CESD, `1` = CESD[CESD >= 16 & !is.na(CESD)], `0` = CESD[CESD < 16 & !is.na(CESD)]))
```

message returns in R: 
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: Vector 1 must be length 419 or one, not 88.

Answer (score 2):

We don't need `recode` here.  Just convert the logical expression to binary with `as.integer`.  The TRUE values are changed to 1 and others to 0 while the `NA` elements in the original data remains the same.

```
data %>%
    mutate(CESD = (CESD >= 16 & !is.na(CESD)) * NA^(is.na(CESD)))
```

---

Or using only `base R`

```
data$CESD <- with(data, (CESD >= 16 & !is.na(CESD)) * NA^(is.na(CESD))))
```

Or we create a logical expression for `NA` elements and update only for the non-NA elements

```
i1 <- !is.na(data$CESD)
data$CESD[i1] <- as.integer(data$CESD[i1] >= 16)
```

which can be written more compactly with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[!is.na(CESD), CESD := as.integer(CESD >= 16)]
```

NOTE: If the values need to `character` class, wrap it with `as.character`

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
data <- data.frame(CESD = sample(c(NA, 1:5, 15:20), 50, replace = TRUE), 
           col2 = rnorm(50))
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code, but NA also be converted to 0. Then I tried `data_new = data %>%
  mutate(CESD = as.integer(CESD >= 16 & !is.na(CESD), CESD < 16 & !is.na(CESD)))` , but it doesn't be fixed, NA is converted to 0 again

Comment: @Jessie DO you want to keep `NA` as `NA`?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep NA as NA

Comment: This could be the answer to a FAQ.